# Why my method doesn't call the another one (undefined variable)

Tags: python, django

Hi I tried a lot and I don't know why when i want to save `haversine()` on x gives me the following error:  `undefined Variable Haversine`. The only way it works it's when I put haversine function inside  get funct

```
class GetRide(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)    
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)     


def haversine(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2 = map(radians, [lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlng = lng2 - lng1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlng/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km


def get(self, request, route_id):

    d_route = Route.objects.get(id=route_id)
    p_routes = Route.objects.all()

    for route in p_routes:
        x = haversine(d_route.origin_lat,d_route.origin_lng, route.origin_lat, route.origin_lng )
        if ( x < 3):
            new_route = 0
    return Response(new_route,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: It looks like your indentation is a bit messed up. The haversine function should also take `self` as its first parameter, as it is a class method. You should also call haversine with `self.haversine`

Comment: Thanks why i need it to call it from self. ?

Comment: Because it won't be found otherwise, as you have discovered already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line:

```
def haversine(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):
```

should be:

```
def haversine(self, lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):
```

and line:

```
x = haversine(d_route.origin_lat,d_route.origin_lng, route.origin_lat, route.origin_lng )
```

should be:

```
x = self.haversine(d_route.origin_lat,d_route.origin_lng, route.origin_lat, route.origin_lng )
```

that is because they both live inside of the `Class` also all of the functions should be indented into the `Class`. Not sure if it is pasted incorrectly or does it actually look like that in the .py file.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the `haversine` function inside of the `GetRide` class. Declaring it inside of the class makes it an instance methods of the class. Instance methods must be called from an instance of the class.

```
# Call it directly from a `GetRide` instance
my_get_ride = GetRide() # create an instance of the class
my_get_ride.haversine(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) # call it from the instance

# Or call it from within another method of `GetRide` from self
def get(self, ...):
    self.haversine(...)
```

Given that you have not declared `haversine` with a `self` parameter, both of these calls would give this error:

```
TypeError: haversine() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

It says that you gave it 5 because python will automatically pass in the instance as the first parameter before `lat1`. What really happens is this:

```
haversine(my_get_ride, lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)
```

You can correct this by updating your haversine method to take a first parameter of `self` as you have done with the `get` method and then from the `get` method you must call `haversine` from `self.

```
def haversine(self, lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):
    # method body

def get(self, request, route_id):
    # first part of method body
        x = self.haversine(d_route.origin_lat,d_route.origin_lng, route.origin_lat, route.origin_lng )
    # second part of method body
```

---

Alternatively, if you do not wish to include `haversine` in the `GetRide` class you can declare it outside of the class within the same file either before or after the `GetRide` class definition.

```
# here it is defined outside of the class
def haversine(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):
    # method body

class GetRide(APIView):
    # other code
    def get(self, request, route_id):
        # method body
```